# Can't connect to MQTT server using raspberrypi hostname on Android

Tags: kotlin, raspberry-pi, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I'm new to using MQTT and I've started a Mosquitto broker on my Raspberry Pi.
When I try to connect to it from my Windows PC cmd it works fine, I just type `mosquitto_sub -h raspberrypi -t "test/message"` and it subscribes to the topic and sees what I publish in it.

The problem is with connecting my phone to it- I've tried using multiple apps including this one: https://github.com/leonardocavagnis/MQTTClientSample_Android and I can connect to the Raspberry Pi broker only by IP address: `tcp://<ip_address>:1883` works okay, but the IP changes in my local network, so I wanted to use `tcp://raspberrypi:1883` instead to have no problems with connection but it doesn't connect then. What could be the issue?

Comment: What provides the DNS services for your network and is your phone using it?

Comment: If I understand you right then all devices are connected to the same router over wifi

Comment: Your phone does not have an mDNS client, so it can't resolve local hostnames.  Windows and Raspbiean do have this client.

Comment: So if I understand right- static IP on RPI is the only way to achieve a stable connection address for phone and further endpoints like wemos?

Comment: @JDAllen Windows don't have a mDNS client unless something has changed recently. (The only way to get one was to install the Apple Printer drivers)

Comment: @PatrykLipka Getting your router to issue the Pi a Static IP will probably be the easiest option.

Comment: @hardillb thanks, I've set static IP on Raspberry PI with a value 125 higher than minimum that my router sets dynamically to devices, that buffer should be enough

Comment: @hardillb Windows 10 has one....at least my v20H2 (19042.867) resolves them.